# What is the opposite of ("key" in obj ) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

This might seem very easy,
but here is my question,what is the opposite of

```
if('name' in obj)
```

Is it `if(!'name' in obj)` or `if("name" not in obj)` or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just wrap it in parens:

```
if( !( 'name' in obj ) ){
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be like this:

```
if (!('name' in obj)) {
    // 'name' not found in obj
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`"name" in obj` is just a boolean expression, just like `a && b || c`. You can negate it like any other expression: `!("name" in obj)`.

Answer (score 2):

there are a few  ways, like:

```
if (!('name' in obj))
if (Object.keys(obj).indexOf('name')<0)
```

Comment: Worth noting that the first will return false if `obj.name` is falsey, so doesn't reliably tell you if *obj* has a property called *name*. The second will include inherited properties (which may not be what the OP wants), the third depends on support for ES5.

Comment: Your first option is not the same as your second: `obj = {name : null}; !obj['name'] === true; !('name' in obj) === false`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName))
```

which checks for a property on the object itself. To include inherited properties, other answers using the `in` operator will do.